# (Can't initialize) TypeError: (0 , firebase_compat_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.getFirestore) is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am trying initialize Firebase in next.js the error I recieve is
`TypeError: (0 , firebase_compat_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.getFirestore) is not a function`

Here is the code I used, I expect it to initialise but it keeps saying that `getFirestore(App)` or `initializeApp(clientCredentials)` is the cause of the error

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/compat/firestore";

const clientCredentials = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);   

export const DB = getFirestore(App)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use Firebase Modular SDK for new projects but here you are using the compact library. To [**Initialize Cloud Firestore**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) it with Modular SDK and the same follows with all other Firebase services like Authentication. You can do as follows:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);   

export const DB = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Make sure you have the latest versions of the Firebase packages installed. You can update them by running the following command:

```
npm install firebase@latest
```

Reference : [**Initialize Cloud Firestore**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize)